# The Etymology of the Term "Nuclear Operators"

Tags: functional-analysis, terminology, banach-spaces, math-history, locally-convex-spaces

Grothendieck in his "Résumé " on the metric theory of topological tensor products, defines the notion of nuclear operators on Banach spaces. My question is, is anyone aware as to why these are known as *nuclear* operators? Of course they are an extension of the trace class operators, say in the Hilbert space setting, but I have never truly understood why they are called nuclear. Did it perhaps to do with nuclear conflict in the 1950s (when this paper was published)? I know Grothendieck was known for political activism and opposition to war. Sorry if these are silly guesses, I am unable to find anything on this choice of name, and am puzzled by it.

Comment: nucleus = kernel. $\Rightarrow$ kernel of an integral operator

Comment: Never considered it that way!

Comment: That's how it all started off in the beginning of the 20th century. With Hilbert, Fredholm and others. They considered integral operators, mostly on $L^2$. I think this is also why $L^2$ is called Hilbert space. Later, those cool people around Banach in Lwow came along and saw that most of these operators are linear operators in and between infinite-dimensional spaces and looked at them in a more abstract way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

amsmath's comment "nucleus = kernel..." is an apt one, as 
the "Schwartz kernel theorem" / $\,\ll\,$Théorème des noyaux$\,\gg\,$ in French <sup>1</sup>, is the etymological source of the terms Nuclear operator and Nuclear space.

*A short synopsis*
Grothendieck answered a question put forward to him by L. Schwartz, being his thesis advisor then. He clarified the origin of a locally-convex topology, defined by Schwartz within distribution theory and till then opaque <sup>2</sup>, on the tensor product $\,\mathscr D'\otimes F\,$ which is naturally a subspace of $\,\mathscr L(\mathscr D,F)$.
Grothendieck introduced the projective tensor product $\otimes_\pi$
and coined the term nuclear operator / $\ll$application nucléaire$\gg$ in French, for elements in $\mathscr L(E,F)$ arising from  $E'\hat{\otimes}_\pi F$, where $E,F$ are locally-convex spaces. Previously such operators had  only been analysed in the case $E,F$ being Banach spaces.

*Furthermore,*
he introduced the injective tensor product topology $\otimes_\epsilon$,
and defined a space $\mathcal{N}$ as nuclear if $\mathcal{N}\!\otimes_\pi\! E$ and $\mathcal{N}\!\otimes_\epsilon\! E$ coincide as locally-convex spaces for every $E$
(in fact, it is sufficient to check the equality for $E=\ell^1$, the summable sequences). All the prominent spaces in distribution theory are nuclear.
When restricted to Banach spaces, nuclearity is not a fruitful concept since no infinite-dimensional Banach space is nuclear.

*Regarding your conjecture*
that 'nuclear' stems from the 1950 politics context, I'd like to add that Grothendieck's solutions were like a nuclear blow up$-$not politically or else, but in the further development of functional analysis.
He turned the field upside down, then moved on into Algebraic geometry.

---

<sup>1</sup> See
[Résumé par Grothendieck, Ann. Institut Fourier](http://www.numdam.org/article/AIF_1952__4__73_0.pdf) on page 99

<sup>2</sup> Search for 'nuclear', or start reading on page 8 in
https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/~leila.schneps/grothendieckcircle/Mathematics/chap3.pdf